# Use Powerpoint inking feature on my laptop from Android Tablet

Tags: windows, samsung-galaxy-tab-s-6

When presenting Powerpoint slides via zoom on my Win10 laptop it is convenient to annotate on the slides in response to audience questions etc. Powerpoint has a convenient annotate feature but it's not easy to draw using it via the mouse or laptop touchpad.

On the other hand I do have a nice Android Tablet with an Active Stylus (Samsung S6) where it's a breeze to draw. But is there any way I can hook up the Tablet to the laptop (via a third party app etc. if needed) so that I can use the native Powerpoint annotation feature but via the Tablet.

PS. Right now I use a hack: I open a second zoom instance on my Android Tablet and use zoom's annotate feature (so I can use my stylus). But then the annotations have to be erased after each slide and cannot be saved easily etc.